# sound – Turn off sound except beep (ALSA, Pulseaudio)

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio, mute

I use short beep tone in X.org. I want to keep sound muted (or at minimum volume) except the beep. I use ALSA. I need beep from `xterm` or applications that beep using X.org (xscreensaver).

How can I turn off all sound except beep from ALSA?

Comment: Do you mean a PC speaker beep, or a beep using an ALSA/Pulseaudio device? Which application produces the beep, and how does it produce it (ALSA library, Pulseaudio library, some other library)?

Answer (score 0):

You must set `Speaker` to 0 and keep `Master` on.

Screenshot from alsamixer:

[image: alsamixer screenshor]